# How to add scroll in a textBox in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I want to add a scroll viewer in a textBOX in a windows 8 app. So that user can scroll through his long text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  a scrollviewer into the XAML. Then set the margins of the scrollviewer by cutting and pasting that of the textbox, and set the height and width of textbox  to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrote what Harshit explained and added some pics and Code.

1. Add  a scrollviewer to your XAML
2. Select Margin in Scrollviewer (Best way: Click on the TestViewer-Code in the XAML to select it)
3. Set the Margin Values to Auto
4. Paste (in XAML) the Textbox and paste it in the Scrollviewer-Tag
5. Set the Height and width of Textbox to Auto
6. done!

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="testapp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:newcalapp_winrt"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,4,0,-4">
    <Button Click="showText" Content="ShowText" x:Name="btn" Width="200" Height="56" Margin="1037,620,0,92"></Button>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="outputTextBoxScrollViewer" Margin="57,200,700,400">
        <TextBox x:Name="outputTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="outputTextBlockScrollViewer" Margin="57,450,700,169">
        <TextBlock x:Name="outputTextBlock"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

C#:

```
namespace testapp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        void showText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            //OutputString
            String outputString;

            //Random number
            Random randomizer = new Random();
            int randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0,100000);

            //Some magic with Dates :) Not important!
            ...

            outputTextBox.Text = outputString;
            outputTextBlock.Text = outputString;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ScrollViewerExample]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qDyJ.png">